# Module endomorphism containments

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, and Define $S:= \operatorname{End}(M_R)$ and $U:= \operatorname{End}(M_{\mathrm{End}(_SM)}).$

I need to show $S=U$

So I am having trouble even decoding this, so elements of $S$ are $M$-endomorphisms over some ring $R$

But elements of $U$ are also endomorphisms of $M$ but the scalar field is an endomorphism field of Where the field is also endomorphisms? Really can't wrap my head around this, I need a small hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T={\rm End}({}_SM)$.  Then $S,T,U$ are all subsets of the set of abelian group homomorphisms $M\to M$.

By convention for $s_1,s_2 \in S$ we denote "do $s_1$ then $s_2$" by $s_2s_1$.  Similarly for $u_1,u_2 \in U$ we denote "do $u_1$ then $u_2$" by $u_2u_1$.  However it is the other way round for $T$: for $t_1,t_2 \in T$ we denote "do $t_1$ then $t_2$" by $t_1t_2$.  These conventions allow us to apply elements of $S$ and $U$ from the left to elements of $M$, whilst elements of $T$ (like elements of $R$ may be applied from the right).  This means that the equations below all come down to rearranging brackets.

There is also a natural map from $R$ to abelian group homomorphisms $M\to M$, given by right multiplication.  Let $R^*$ denote the image of this map.  Thus $R^*, S,T,U$ are all subsets of a common set, and to show that $S=U$ it suffices to show that $S\subseteq U$ and $U \subseteq S$.

You know (from definition of endomorphism):

$(fx)\lambda=f(x\lambda) \qquad \forall f\in S, \,\,\lambda \in R$

$(fx)\alpha=f(x\alpha) \qquad \forall f\in S, \,\,\alpha \in T$

$(\Gamma x)\alpha=\Gamma(x\alpha) \qquad \forall \Gamma\in U,\,\, \alpha \in T$

From these equations you must deduce:

1) $S \subseteq U$,

2) $R^* \subseteq T$,

3) (2) implies that $U \subseteq S$.

First write down what it means to be in each of $S,T,U$ and then you should see that each of these 3 statements follows from one of the 3 equations.

Comment: by the do this then that, is the reason because we are in right snd left modules respectively? like the the subscript is on the left we write $s_1,s_2$ as $s_1s_2$ but the other way if we have $M_S$?, want to see if I am understanding correctly.

Comment: Yes, but the other way round: If the subscript is on the left then $s_1$ followed by $s_2$ is $s_2 s_1$.  In other words $(s_2s_1)m=s_2(s_1m)$.

Comment: question, do we get $S \subset U$ for free if I showed $R \subset T$?

Comment: $S\subseteq U$ follows immediately from one of the 3 equations.  It is $U\subseteq S$ that requires $R^*\subseteq T$.  Perhaps it would help if I showed why $S\subseteq U$, as an example of the reasoning required: An abelian group homomorphism $\Gamma\colon M \to M$ lies in U precisely when for all $\alpha \in T$ we have $(\Gamma x)\alpha=\Gamma(x\alpha)$ (for all $x \in M$).  Now pick an arbitrary $f\in S$.  Can you show that it meets this criteria?  If so then you have shown $S\subseteq U$.  The other two parts require precisely the same reasoning.

Comment: Yes because if $f \in S$ then its scalar is $r \in R$ but $R \subset T$ $\Rightarrow$ $r \in T$ so it follows?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "its scalar is $r\in R$".  You need to check that $f$ satisfies the criteria for belonging in $U$.  That is substitute $f$ in for $\Gamma$ in the criteria and check that the resulting equation is true.